# How to simulate pipe append?

Tags: bash, shell-script, pipe

I am using `curlftpfs` to mount remote drive. Unfortunately, with the file located in remote side, I can't use `>>` operation. As I understood from [this link](http://sourceforge.net/p/curlftpfs/discussion/542750/thread/53e47b71/) it's not possible to append to existing file(unless I am mistaken, please correct me). So I have function like this:

```
LogMe()
{
  p="$1"
  DateTime=`date "+%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S"`
  echo $DateTime' : '$p >> $logfile
}
```

`$logfile` is the remote file mounted using `curlftpfs`. How can I modify my function to support appending without using `<<`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The optimum way is to simply ignore curlftpfs for this access, because the ftp
protocol has an *append* command to add data to a file. So setup a one-off
ftp connection just for the update, eg:

```
echo $DateTime' : '$p | 
curl --append -T - ftp://user:password@host/some/logfile
```

This 2nd ftp should not unduly perturb curlftpfs if you don't refer to
the logfile through the mount point.

However, if you prefer to not use a 2nd ftp, you will have to copy
the entire logfile, add the line, then copy it back. The command `sponge`
can help you simplify the task:

```
(cat $logfile; echo $DateTime' : '$p) | sponge $logfile
```

sponge collects all the input into a temporary file, before renaming
it "atomically" to the output file.

Comment: I also came to second solution, although first one considerable as well.